# SQLite: How to compare 2 tables?

Tags: sqlite, string-comparison, sqlite-net

My c# application reads file list from web service 1 and insert full file names to table1, then reads list from the second web service and insert them to table2.

These tables have identical structure, like this:

```
create table table1(id int, filename text)
```

**The task is**: to compare these tables and select the common filenames, and the distinct.

If these table are large the compare is the long executing process.

How to improve it? How to add *hash* field to these tables and how to calculate it automatically?
Other way?

Answer (score 2):

The following join query should do the trick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.filename
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.filename = t2.filename
```

This query could benefit from an index on the `filename` columns in both tables.

Comment: That is network paths and filenames can be long, is index effective on long string?

Comment: Does it make sense to add hash field?

Comment: AFAIK SQLite only used B-Tree as its index.